# Move containers before scale-in in an AutoScalingGroup

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I have an AutoScalingGroup defined via cdk running with self-managed (non Fargate) EC2 instances.

```
class RcsECSClusterStack(NestedStack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, 
                 configs: dict,
                 vpc_stack: Stack,
                 sec_grp_stack: Stack,
                 efs_stack: Stack,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self.cluster = ecs.Cluster(
            self,
            configs["server"]["cluster"]["name"],
            cluster_name=configs["server"]["cluster"]["name"],
            vpc=vpc_stack.vpc
        )

        self.cluster_launch_template_user_data = ec2.UserData.for_linux()
        self.cluster_launch_template = ec2.LaunchTemplate(
            self,
            configs["server"]["cluster"]["launch_template_name"],
            launch_template_name=configs["server"]["cluster"]["launch_template_name"],
            machine_image=ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazon_linux2(),
            role=self.cluster_launch_template_iam_role,
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
                getattr(ec2.InstanceClass, configs["server"]["cluster"]["instance"]["class"]), 
                getattr(ec2.InstanceSize, configs["server"]["cluster"]["instance"]["size"])
            ),
            key_name=self.cluster_launch_template_key_pair.key_name,
            user_data=self.cluster_launch_template_user_data,
            security_group=sec_grp_stack.cluster_security_group,
            
        )

        self.cluster_launch_template.apply_removal_policy(
            RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
        )
        self.autoscaling_group = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(
            self,
            configs["server"]["cluster"]["asg_name"],
            vpc=vpc_stack.vpc,
            min_capacity=1,
            max_capacity=5,
            update_policy=autoscaling.UpdatePolicy.rolling_update(
                max_batch_size=1,
                min_success_percentage=0,
                suspend_processes=[
                    autoscaling.ScalingProcess.HEALTH_CHECK,
                    autoscaling.ScalingProcess.REPLACE_UNHEALTHY,
                    autoscaling.ScalingProcess.AZ_REBALANCE,
                    autoscaling.ScalingProcess.ALARM_NOTIFICATION,
                    autoscaling.ScalingProcess.SCHEDULED_ACTIONS
                ],
                wait_on_resource_signals=True
            ),
            launch_template=self.cluster_launch_template,
            signals=autoscaling.Signals.wait_for_all(
                timeout=Duration.minutes(10)
            ),
            default_instance_warmup=Duration.seconds(20),
            ssm_session_permissions=True,
            termination_policies=[
                autoscaling.TerminationPolicy.OLDEST_LAUNCH_TEMPLATE, 
                autoscaling.TerminationPolicy.OLDEST_INSTANCE, 
                autoscaling.TerminationPolicy.DEFAULT
            ],
            group_metrics=[autoscaling.GroupMetrics.all()]
        )
        self.autoscaling_group.apply_removal_policy(
            policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
        )
        self.autoscaling_group.scale_on_cpu_utilization(
            "ecsclusterid",
            target_utilization_percent=60
        )

        self.capacity_provider = ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(
            self,
            configs["server"]["cluster"]["asg_cp_name"],
            capacity_provider_name=configs["server"]["cluster"]["asg_cp_name"],
            auto_scaling_group=self.autoscaling_group,
            enable_managed_scaling=True,
            enable_managed_termination_protection=True,
            can_containers_access_instance_role=False
        )

        self.cluster.add_asg_capacity_provider(self.capacity_provider)
```

But as I have only running 5 containers at the time, mostly 2 instances are used.

The problem occurs, if I update the AutoScalingGroup / EC2 stack:

- An old instance is terminated
- then a new one is started up

but during the termination, the container running on the old instance is shutdown as well and not started on another instance beforehand.

Is there a scaling policy that can do that automatically? Or a metric, which could be used for that?

This could be solved by only using the capacity provider, but after activating it, it does not scale at all -> my tasks never start because of MEM oder ENI usage reasons but the capacity provider does not react on these.
Therefore I am looking for metrics to solve this issue.

Comment: Please add your (minimal) CDK code to the question.

Comment: Done, thanks :)